# %M shows full month name instead of abbreviation

Tags: php

I am getting a timedate row and converting it into a more presentable looking phrase.  I used `%M` so that it would show "Dec" instead of "December" but it still only shows the full month name. The little `%m` shows "05" instead of the "Dec" like it's supposed to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `%M`?  That's not how [`date`](http://php.net/date) works.  What function are you using to format your timestamp?  Show us the code, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), it's  `%b` that shows abbreviated month names like what you want.

Comment: why you removed your answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777366/php-mysql-order-table-code-error-cannot-parse-query)?

Comment: @JessePfieffer : If you feel this is answer, could you mark it as accepted. See [here how to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

`%M` is used for short textual representation of a month, three letters.

Use `%F` for  full textual representation of a month, such as `January` or `March`

Comment: According to the question 'M' is giving him the full month name and he already knows that it stands for the 3-letter abbreviation.

Comment: Right!  I know what it is supposed to stand for... thats why I'm so confused!  I have no earthly idea how I am doing this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

You aren't calling the PHP function `date()`, but the MySQL (so I assume) function `DATE_FORMAT()`, so you'll need to write `%b` instead of `%M`.