# PHP MySQL order table code error "cannot parse query"

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm trying to get a table to sort via its header title. But I get the cannot parse query. Is it something I'm doing wrong in the MySQL?

I have to order a table of Jargon for work which contains thousands of records. So I'm just practising it at home to get it right. However at the moment I seem to be getting stuck on that MySQL bit. I followed the tips on a different website which had this code but still getting stuck a explanation of why this isn't working will help.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="../demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    function makeHeaderLink($value, $key, $col, $dir) {
        $out = "<a href=\"" . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . "?c=";
        //set column query string value
        switch($key) {
            case "Acronym":
                $out .= "1";
                break;
            case "Full Name":
                $out .= "2";
                break;
            case "What":
                $out .= "3";
                break;
            default:
                $out .= "0";
        }

        $out .= "&d=";

        //reverse sort if the current column is clicked
        if($key == $col) {
            switch($dir) {
                case "ASC":
                    $out .= "1";
                    break;
                default:
                    $out .= "0";
            }
        }
        else {
            //pass on current sort direction
            switch($dir) {
                case "ASC":
                    $out .= "0";
                    break;
                default:
                    $out .= "1";
            }
        }

        //complete link
        $out .= "\">$value</a>";

        return $out;
    }

    switch($_GET['c']) {
        case "1":
            $col = "Acronym";
            break;
        case "2":
            $col = "Full_Name";
            break;
        case "3":
            $col = "What";
            break;
                }

    if($_GET['d'] == "1") {
        $dir = "DESC";
    }
    else {
        $dir = "ASC";
    }

    if(!$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password")) {
        echo "Cannot connect to db server";
    }
    elseif(!mysql_select_db("nazir_jargon")) {
        echo "Cannot select database";
    }
    else {

        if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT 'Acronym', 'Full Name', 'What' * FROM jargon1 ORDER BY $col $dir")) {
            echo "Cannot parse query";
        }
        elseif(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
            echo "No records found";
        }
        else {
            echo "<table class=\"bordered\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>" . makeHeaderLink("Acronym", "Acronym", $col, $dir) . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . makeHeaderLink("Full Name", "Full_Name", $col, $dir) . "</th>";
            echo "<th>" . makeHeaderLink("What", "What", $col, $dir) . "</th>";
            echo "</tr>\n";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
                echo "<tr><td>$row[person_id]</td><td>$row[Acronym]</td><td>$row[Full_Name]</td><td>$row[What]</td></tr>\n";
            }
            echo "</table><br />\n";
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: What does mysql_error() output?

Comment: Are these single quotes around the field names within the query? Remove 'em

Comment: use [**`dataTable`**](http://www.datatables.net/examples/), you don't have to fire query again and again.

Comment: thanks Guys I got it working :D

    if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT `Acronym`, `Full Name`, `What` FROM `jargon1` ORDER BY $col $dir"))

The order works for Acronym and What however when I try it on Full Name I get the same Parse error isit anything todo with the space in between 'Full Name'.

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove single quote & ***** from the query so that query should look like below. I hope it will work.

```
SELECT Acronym, Full Name, What FROM jargon1 ORDER BY $col $dir
```

If it won't work,

Can you print

```
echo "SELECT Acronym, Full Name, What FROM jargon1 ORDER BY $col $dir";
```

and let me know what you get?

**Note:** I think you wanted to use backticks(`), however mistakenly used single quote.

---

### Edit 1

As you see

```
echo "SELECT Acronym, Full Name, What FROM jargon1 ORDER BY $col $dir";
```

prints

```
SELECT Acronym, Full Name, What FROM jargon1 ORDER BY ASC`
```

That means `$col` is not printing.. please check what is going wrong with `$col`

```
SELECT Acronym, Full Name, What FROM jargon1 ORDER BY columnNameMissing ASC`
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Hi Fahim Thanks for the suggestions your right I wanted to use Backticks :p

That didnt work I still get the same error. after printing echo I get:

SELECT Acronym, Full Name, What FROM jargon1 ORDER BY ASC

Comment: I've tried the query without the other order codes i.e. the Asc and desc and I can get the data in the table however when I try to do it using the above code I get that error. Ideally I want to use Jquery tableorder however I want todo it within PHP first as I want to understand it better.

Comment: as you see echo prints `SELECT Acronym, Full Name, What FROM jargon1 ORDER BY ASC` means `$col` is not printing.. please check what is going wrong with `$col`

Comment: Yep the problem is solved :) Im just trying to implement pagination now :D

Comment: @NazirJauhar : Okay.. so problem was with $col or backticks?

Comment: the problem was the backticks.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the * from your select query if you are specifying the columns returned. Otherwise get everything back with the *. One or the other.

Comment: Hello Chevy, you can edit your answer to add examples/demonstrations of what you mean. Please do that rather than adding comments (use the "edit" link right below the text of your answer).

Comment: Thanks chevy tried that but I still get the same error unfortunately.